# How to use LIKE and CONCAT() with variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query using T-SQL.

**Goal**: return rows that contain a name stored in a variable.

**My issue**: the query returns all rows, without filtering.

**Additional info**: The names are stored as `varchar` and there are several spaces after the letters which is why I want to concatenate the variable with '%'.

Also, when I ran the query with just one '%' appended on the end of the variable, the database returned all records beginning with 'D'.

**My query**:

```
DECLARE @fName as varchar;
SET @fName='DILLON';

SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL_ADDRESS
FROM 
    [172.20.11.11].LSLMDB.dbo.vwEmployee e
JOIN 
    [172.20.11.11].LSLMDB.ls_apps.PAEMPLOYEE pa ON pa.EMPLOYEE = e.EMPLOYEE
JOIN
    [172.20.11.11].LSLMDB.ls_apps.PCODES pc ON pa.LOCAT_CODE = pc.CODE
JOIN
    [172.20.11.11].LSLMDB.ls_apps.PCODESDTL pcd ON pc.CODE = pcd.CODE 
WHERE 
    e.FIRST_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%',@fName,'%');
```

I appreciate any attempts to help!

Comment: Always, *always* declare your `varchar` variables with an explicit length. Lest you end up with one that's unexpectedly only one character long, like you're running into now. It's a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: While the solution was fairly simple to solve, this question was very well asked... thanks for putting in the effort and welcome to SO Dillion.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to see the community is quite responsive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the system is defaulting to `DECLARE @fName as varchar(1)` -- this is probably not what you want.  Change to `DECLARE @fName as varchar(100);`  This should work as expected.

> the query returns all rows, without filtering.

No it is returning all rows that contain `D`.  Depending on coallation settings this might include both upper and lower case matches

> Also, when I ran the query with just one '%' appended on the end of the variable, the database returned all records beginning with 'D'.

Since it was just a single character the filter became `D%` which would return all records starting with D.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Overlooked that... My rep won't let the vote change publicly, just so you know.

Comment: @DillonHarless -- I think you just have to wait for a few minutes before you can vote at your level.  Good Luck.